# Comment text box for drop down list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, dropdown

I have a list in SharePoint with a few drop down selectors where you can select various predetermined options.

I was wondering if it's possible to have a bottom option such as "n/a" or "Other" where after you click on that drop down option, it will display a text box that you must provide more details for.

Maybe there is some way to use Fill in options to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options to achieve your requirements

**(1) OOTB Solution**

In the choice field settings, you can allow `Fill In` option to **Specify your own value**.

[image]

- **Advantage of this solution:**

  - No code required
- **Disadvantage of this solution**

  - The issue of this solution, it always shows a text box to add your own value whatever the selected value is other or not.

[image]

---

**(2) Custom Solution**

You can use **SPUtitlity** to show and hide the other field based on a Choice field selection.

```
    if(selectedFieldValue != 'Other') {
       SPUtility.GetSPField('Other Title').Hide();
      }
    else {
       SPUtility.GetSPField('Other Title').Show();
      }
```

Check the detail steps of using **SPutility** at  [how and hide fields based on a Choice field selection in ‘New Form’, ‘Edit Form’ and ‘Display Form’ in SharePoint via SPUtility.js](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/25/show-hide-fields-based-on-a-drop-down-using-sputility-js/)

- **Advantage Of this Solution:**

  - It will satisfy and match your requirements.
- **Disadvantage of this solution**

  - It will require some script and customization

Check also [How to show and hide fields based on Choice field selection in New Form, Edit Form and Display Form in SharePoint via Jquery?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: I like your break down and also the fact that you provided more in-depth steps in the link. I'll have to give this a go over the weekend. Much appreciated.

Comment: I tried this over the weekend and again earlier this week and I'm getting this strange error when I try to select "Default New Form" or "Default Edit Form" from the Customize List section of the edit ribbon. I'm working with Microsoft on the issue but they are being quite slow about it. I'm not sure if it's an error on my end or if the system is experiencing issues right now, but I'm hoping it'll be resolved soon!